# Gnosis safe without safe nonce

Tags: nonce, gnosis-safe, gnosis

Is there any way of creating a Gnosis safe without using "safe nonces" ? I would like to automate certain transactions from a pool of already signed transactions but don't know the order.

Comment: You would have to use modules for this: https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/contracts/modules-1

Comment: Did you found any answers regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need to know the nonce before signing the transaction, as the nonce becomes part of the signed data.

You can get the last nonce by fetching the list of pending and completed transactions using the safe API:

```
def get_nonce():
    transaction_service_api.get_transactions(my_safe_address)

    if not txns:
        return 0

    return txs[0]['nonce'] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Gnosis Safe without "safe nonces" is not a typical practice, as Gnosis Safe uses safe nonces to ensure the order and execution of transactions within the Safe.  Safe nonces help prevent a transaction from being replayed out of order or executed more than once.